# disable row select extjs mvc

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

i am using checkboxmodel to select rows but i want to make some rows to be selection disabled based on some logic...
here is my what i am trying but 'beforeselect' function doesn't even fires

```
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
      checkOnly: true,
    mode:'multi',
   listeners: {
     beforeselect:function(grid){
    var grid=Ext.getCmp('mylist');     
        var selectionModel=grid.getSelectionModel();
    var selectedRecords=selectionModel.getSelection();
    var myValue=selectedRecords[0].get('nowreceive');
    var myvalue1=selectedRecords[0].get('received');
    if(myValue>myvalue1)
    {return false;}
    else 
    return true;
        }}  }
    ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beforecellmousedown event in the view config works for me.This is done in the viewconfig of the grid...

```
 viewConfig: {
 listeners: {
 beforecellmousedown: function(view, cell, cellIdx, record, row, rowIdx, eOpts){
               var myvalue=record.get('quantity_ordered');
               var myvalue1=record.get('quantity_received')
               if(myvalue==myvalue1)
               {
               return false;
               }
                   else {
                   return true;
                   }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you know the event is not firing? It should be, but my guess is that `selectedRecords[0]` is not defined and that crashes your execution, because `getSelection()` probably returns an empty array, before any selection has occurred.

What you should do is to use the second argument of [`beforeselect`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel-event-beforeselect), which is the record that's going to be added to the selection.

So you can implement your listener in a much simpler way:

```
beforeselect: function (selModel, record) {
    if (record.get('nowreceive') > record.get('received')) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's true, beforeselect not firing,i tried what u say, i also tried simply this..  beforeselect: function (selModel, record) {
  alert('d'); ...but nothing from firebug/firefox

Comment: What version of Ext are you using? You should try adding the listener directly to the grid panel, instead of the selection model. [`beforeselect` for grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-event-beforeselect) is available since 4.0.0, while it is only available since 4.0.2 for [`CHeckboxModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel-event-beforeselect)...

Comment: cannt find beforeselect function for grid

Comment: It's an event, not a function. [Here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-beforeselect)'s the correct link. According to your comment, your problem doesn't come from that though. I think we'll need the entire code of your grid definition to find what's wrong.